# Most efficient way to forward fill a bit array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, bit-manipulation

Imagine you have a bit array (any data type is okay. e.g. list, np.array, bitarray, bitmap, etc of booleans) that is randomly filled. What is the fastest way to “forward fill” (left to right, or 0th index to nth index) that array in Python such that n bits get set to 1 following each bit already set to 1?

For example, take the array below:

`[01000100000]`

Given n=2 the forward filled array would be:

`[01110111000]`

**edit**

Assume that the input is a bit array of 10,000 elements, of which a random 20% are true, and n=25. This can be represented as a python list with 10,000 boolean elements, of which 20% are `True`. This could also be represented as a `set` with 2,000 `int` elements between 0 and 10,000.

**edit 2**

To get things started, here are some examples using the parameters above:

```
new = set()
new.update(*[range(i, i+25) for i in existing])
# 2.34 ms ± 56.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
new = BitMap()  # This is a pyroaring BitMap
for e in existing:
    new.add_range(e, e+25)
# 461 µs ± 6.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: What is the data type exactly? `[0100010000]` is quite ambiguous.

Comment: It can be any data type. I'm looking for the fastest way agnostic of the final data type. I mentioned a few in the question: list, np.array, bitarray, bitmap, set, etc.

Comment: It's impossible to answer "most efficient" or "fastest way" without choosing an actual data structure. You need to pick a type and show what you tried. For example, given a bitvec (e.g., with u64's underlying storage) you will take a vastly different approach than if you have a list of bools.

Comment: No, the data structure should not be chosen first. The data structure to pick depends on the actual *problem* and its *context*. So, the question is: what is the *precise* problem that as to be solved. What are the constraints or the use-case for this? For example: is the input big or small? Is the number of bit fixed? Is it bounded? etc.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I edited the question to attend to your questions above. The input is fairly small, and the number can be fixed. I agree that the data structures shouldn't be chosen, because each data structure will have its own optimal answer. I'm looking for the global optimal answer available in python.

Comment: Is `n` a constant (fixed) or a variable? Do you plan to perform other operation on the bitset and if yes, what kind?

Answer (score 1):

I have addressed several datatypes below. There are no timings given, you might want to time the statement setting `ans` or refactor-in functions to time at the granularity that makes sense to you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Dec 19 09:08:56 2021

for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397220/most-efficient-way-to-forward-fill-a-bit-array

@author: paddy
"""

from random import sample


n = 2  # bits to the right of set bits to also set 
elements = 17
true_percent = 20.0


#%% Using arbitrary precision int
print("\nUsing arbitrary precision int.\n".upper())
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce


# Set some random bits True
bits = sum(1 << r 
           for r in sample(range(elements), int(true_percent/100 * elements)))

# Set n right-adjacent bits.
ans = reduce(or_, (bits >> x for x in range(n+1)), 0)

# Print
print(f"Random bits = {bits:0{elements}b}")
if 1: 
    print()
    for x in range(n+1):
        print(f"              {bits >> x:0{elements}b}")
    print()
print(f"Answer      = {ans:0{elements}b}\n")


#%% Using list.
print("\nUsing list.\n".upper())
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce


bits = [0] * elements
# Set some random bits to 1
for r in sample(range(elements), int(true_percent/100 * elements)):
    bits[r] = 1

# Set n right-adjacent bits.
#   [0]*x is padding bits on the left.
#   zip(*(list1, list2,..)) returns the n'th elements on list1, list2,...
#   int(any(...)) or's them.
ans = [int(any(shifts)) 
       for shifts in zip(*([0]*x + bits for x in range(n+1)))]

# Print
print(f"Random bits = {bits}")
if 1: 
    print()
    for x in range(n+1):
        print(f"              {[0]*x + bits}")
    print()
print(f"Answer      = {ans}\n")


#%% Using numpy.

# Adapt the list solution to use numpy operators on numpy arrays


#%% Using other ordered collections such as str.

# Convert to and from int solution.
```

**Sample Output:**

```
USING ARBITRARY PRECISION INT.

Random bits = 01000000010000010

              01000000010000010
              00100000001000001
              00010000000100000

Answer      = 01110000011100011


USING LIST.

Random bits = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

Answer      = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```